# ImageView does not respect Pivot when using setRotation()

Tags: android, imageview, vector-graphics

I have been struggling too much with this problem. I tried every possible solution I found on the web. NOTHING works!!!

Anyway, I am trying to make an analog clock view using svg Vectors for my app. I had successfully implemented the clock face and was able to display the clock dials in the center.

However, I can not rotate the clock's dials from the center. I am pretty much sure that my pivotX and pivotY variables are pointing to exactly the center. But still, the hands rotate to a different pivot I don't even know where is it.

I even tried duplicating the VectorDrawableCompat class and accessing the Vector  tag to manually change position but it didn't work.

I already tried every possible solution I thought of and everything that might help me but still no result.

```
package com.analogclock.me;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.analogclock.me.vectors.VectorDrawableCompat;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AnalogClockView extends RelativeLayout{

    int color;
    int fontSize;
    float alpha;
    AppCompatImageView analogFace;
    AppCompatImageView analogHour;
    AppCompatImageView analogMinute;
    AppCompatImageView analogSecond;
    Drawable hour;
    Drawable minute;
    Drawable second;
    Drawable face;
    public View c;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    public AnalogClockView(Context ctx) {//// TODO: try adding pivot parameters.
        super(ctx);
        main(ctx);
        setClipChildren(false);
    }

    com.analogclock.vectors.VectorDrawableCompat.VGroup vGroup;
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener;
    int centerX;
    int centerY;
    public void main(Context ctx) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);

        alpha = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getFloat("opacity", 0.25f);
        fontSize = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getInt("font size", 40);
        color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getInt("clock color", 0xffffffff);

        //todo Make a method for setting size based on @fontSize variable
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            face = ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.analog_clock_1);
            hour = ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.hours_hand);
            minute = ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.minutes_hand);
            second = ctx.getDrawable(R.drawable.second_hand);
        }else{
            face = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.analog_clock_1);
            hour = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hours_hand);
            minute = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.minutes_hand);
            second = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.second_hand);
        }

        face = DrawableCompat.  wrap(face);
        hour = DrawableCompat.  wrap(hour);
        minute = DrawableCompat.wrap(minute);
        second = DrawableCompat.wrap(second);

        DrawableCompat.setTint(face.mutate(),color);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(hour.mutate(),color);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(minute.mutate(),color);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(second.mutate(),color);

        second = DrawableCompat.unwrap(second);

        inflate(ctx,R.layout.style2_analog,this);

        analogFace = (AppCompatImageView)findViewById(R.id.face);
        analogHour = (AppCompatImageView)findViewById(R.id.hour);
        analogMinute = (AppCompatImageView)findViewById(R.id.minute);
        analogSecond = (AppCompatImageView)findViewById(R.id.second);

        c = findViewById(R.id.c);

        //square it
        analogFace.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        analogHour.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        analogMinute.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        analogSecond.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        analogFace.setImageDrawable(face);
        analogHour.setImageDrawable(hour);
        analogMinute.setImageDrawable(minute);
        analogSecond.setImageDrawable(second);

        final int dp = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,7.0f,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


        //analogHour.setPadding(0,0,0,);

        layoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.e("analoghour",analogHour.getX()+"x-y"+analogHour.getY());
                centerY = (analogFace.getTop() + analogFace.getBottom()) / 2;
                centerX = (analogFace.getLeft() + analogFace.getRight()) / 2;

                analogHour.setY(analogHour.getTop() - analogHour.getHeight()/2 + dp);
                analogMinute.setY(analogMinute.getTop() - analogMinute.getHeight()/2 + dp);
                analogSecond.setY(analogSecond.getTop() - analogSecond.getHeight()/2 + dp);

                com.analogclock.vectors.VectorDrawableCompat compat =
                        com.analogclock.vectors.VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(),R.drawable.second_hand,null);
                if (compat != null) {
                    compat.setAllowCaching(false);
                    analogSecond.setImageDrawable(compat);
                    VectorDrawableCompat.VGroup vGroup = (VectorDrawableCompat.VGroup) compat.getTargetByName("rotation");
                    Log.e("isNull", (vGroup == null) + "");
                    if (vGroup != null) {
                        vGroup.setPivotX(centerX);
                        vGroup.setPivotY(centerX);
                        Log.e("fddf y",""+  vGroup.getPivotY());
                      Log.e("fddf x",""+  vGroup.getPivotX());
                        analogSecond.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                        analogSecond.setClipBounds(analogFace.getClipBounds());
                        analogSecond.setPivotX(centerX);
                        analogSecond.setPivotY(centerX);
                        analogSecond.setRotation(50);
                        vGroup.setRotation(50);
                        compat.invalidateSelf();
                        analogSecond.invalidate();
                        AnalogClockView.this.invalidate();
                        ((LinearLayout)AnalogClockView.this.getParent()).invalidate();

                    }

                }




                invalidate();

                setTime();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
                }else{
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(layoutListener);
                }
            }
        };
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);


    }

    public void setTime() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int curSecond = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int curMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int curHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    }


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why the heck are you doing all that work after layout?  That all looks like stuff that should be done in onDraw by using rotation matrices on the canvas before drawing the drawables, not by mutating them and creating rotated drawables.  99.999% of the time if you think you need a GlobalLayoutListener, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Also, why is this a child of RelativeLayout, rather than just a child of View?  There's no children involved, so there's no reason for it to be a layout.

Comment: @GabeSechan I will try using onDraw() . I am extending Relative Layout because I am using a layout resource file that has RelativeLayout as its root.

Comment: And it has children that are ImageViews

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  The root of the layout file a View is used in has no effect on what the parent of that View should be.  The only time to extend RelativeLayout is if that view itself has children that need to be arranged relatively.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah.  Ok, I relooked and see it now.  You're just approaching this wrong from start to finish.  This shouldn't have multiple views.  This should be one view, not a layout, with a custom onDraw.  Your entire approach is making everything far more difficult.

Comment: @GabeSechan I know that this regularly needs to use canvas but using canvas won't be as good as making vector graphics in terms of design.

Comment: Using canvas doesn't mean not using SVG.  You can draw any type of drawable to a canvas.

Comment: @GabeSechan And this class needs to work with other clock faces so that I only have to change drawables

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok I will try onDraw() now